# Rolling mean of Time series Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to learn about rolling statistics. I created a data frame for :

```
d = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
s = Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```

as :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import time
r = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
r
len(r)
[r[i] for i in range(len(r))]
s = Series(randn(len(r)), index=r)
s
s.plot()
df_new = DataFrame(data = s, columns=['Random Number Generated'])
df_new.diff().hist()
```

Now I am trying to find the rolling mean of the series over the last 3 hours in a new column on a DataFrame. I tried to find the rolling mean first:

```
df_new['mean'] = rolling_mean(df_new, window=3)
```

Am I correct ? But the result doesn't look like mean. Can someone explain me this one please.

Comment: What do you mean "the result doesn't look like mean"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have NaN for first 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

I have rerun your code and could not find any problems. It seems to work.
If you want to take the rolling mean over the last 3 hours, `rolling_mean(df_new, window=5)` should be `rolling_mean(df_new, window=3)`

Here is my code for the verification.

```
import numpy as np

window = 3
mean_list = []
val_list = []
for i, val in enumerate(s):
    val_list.append(val)
    if i < window - 1:
        mean_list.append(np.nan)
    else:
        mean_list.append(np.mean(np.array(val_list)))
        val_list.pop(0)
df_new['mean2'] = mean_list
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
                     Random Number Generated      mean     mean2
2011-01-01 00:00:00                 1.457483       NaN       NaN
2011-01-01 01:00:00                 0.009979       NaN       NaN
2011-01-01 02:00:00                 0.581128  0.682864  0.682864
2011-01-01 03:00:00                 1.905528  0.832212  0.832212
2011-01-01 04:00:00                 2.221040  1.569232  1.569232
2011-01-01 05:00:00                 0.696211  1.607593  1.607593
2011-01-01 06:00:00                -0.854759  0.687497  0.687497
2011-01-01 07:00:00                -0.033226 -0.063925 -0.063925
2011-01-01 08:00:00                 0.097187 -0.263599 -0.263599
2011-01-01 09:00:00                -1.579210 -0.505083 -0.505083
...
```

The results by `rolling_mean` is consistent with manually calculated rolling mean values.

Another way to confirm the validity is looking at the plots of calculated rolling mean. pandas.DataFrame prepares `plot` method to draw graph easily.

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot 
 df_new.plot()
 pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was confused to see Nan as mean. Tats why asked for verification. Thanks :)

Comment: That's because of the definition of the rolling mean. You cannot get a value from (x_{t-2} + x_{t-1} + x_t) / 3 for t=1 and t=2 since the time series does not have x_{t-2} and x_{t-1}. That's how they return NaN as outputs.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your index is a timestamp (as it currently is), you can just use resample:

```
s.resample('3H')
```

When you use random numbers, it is best to set a seed value so that others can replicate your results.

```
np.random.seed(0)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H'))
s.plot();s.resample('3H').plot()
```

[image]